# HDMI Monitor 1600x900, VGA monitor 1366x768 - VGA 1600x900 doesn't look right

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, extended-desktop

I have two Radeon 7700 video cards.

I have an HDMI cord plugged into one video card, and a VGA plugged into the same card which gives me extended display dual monitors. Apparently I can't do two HDMIs off both of the cards for some reason.

The monitors are both the exact same make and model.

The HDMI is set to 1600x900 display and looks great on my TV monitor.

The VGA is set to 1366x768 and looks great, but it's too small a resolution.

When I set the VGA to 1600x900 it doesn't take up the full screen on my monitor. There's black space above it and to the sides. But the 1366x768 works as full screen.

Does anyone know why this is? It'd be nice to have dual 1600x900 displays.

Comment: It sounds like the monitor maybe scaling the VGA signal incorrectly. Try using the physical menu buttons on the monitor connected to the 1600X900 VGA signal and use the built in "auto scale" or "auto adjust" feature. You may also try power cycling the monitor after you set the resolution to 1600X900.